# Who else did Richard Harrow kill in Season 3, Episode 1?

Tags: character, boardwalk-empire

Near the end of Season 3 Episode 1 of *Boardwalk Empire*, Richard Harrow kills two men: Manny Horvitz and somebody else.

- Is that "somebody else" significant?
- Was it Roland Smith (a.k.a. the thief's wheelman from earlier in the episode)?
- Or was it simply a wheelman for the occasion and nothing more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**He's pretty likely an unlucky driver/minion of Manny's.**

I don't think we have enough information to be sure, but based on:

1. The victims location (sitting outside Manny's house waiting in a car), and
2. The context (Manny's response to hearing a honk indicates that he was expecting to be picked up),

I think it's safe to assume that Richard's mission to avenge the murder of Tommy's parents by killing Manny also claimed the life of a hapless wheelman or accomplice for Manny's planned trip that night.

Comment: Not to forget the planned trip was actually to kill Rowland Smith.